# Does the PERC 5/i Integrated controller support SATA II/III?

Tags: ssd, sata, sas, dell-perc

I have a refurb 2950 with a PERC 5/i Integrated controller. Currently, there are 4x 3.5" SAS drives in use, with two slots available. I want to add two SSDs (using a 3.5" ICY dock) in RAID1 in the extra slots.

Are SATA II (or III) SSDs compatible with PERC 5/i Integrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"6 x 3.5” Hard Drive Option: 3.5” HD Option: up to 6 SAS (10K/15K) or SATA (7.2K) drives;"

If the SSD/ICY would work in a vanilla SATA port on any other server, it should work here - provided that you can get the ICY in there without breaking something.

Comment: I ordered a SATA III SSD and I'm going to try it out. I'll follow up as testing progresses. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, I'd be interested in the results myself!

Comment: Follow up: worked just fine. :)